# Scheduling a Rails task to safely backup the database file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, backup, scheduled-tasks

I have a Rails application on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The application uses a sqlite database, and I need to backup it once a day. The backup should be done by coping the database file to a mirrored folder, and a mirror-backup service will take it from there.

There is one problem. I would like to avoid copying the database file while the application uses it. If I copy the file in the middle of an action, I'll get a corrupted and\or locked database file in the backup - and restoring such a file is too much trouble, if it's even possible.

Now, is there a make the scheduled task wait until the database is not in use? Or to prevent the rest of the application from using the database while the backup task is running?

As for the scheduling, I've seen several solutions, but I haven't committed to a scheduling solution yet, so it's possible for me to depend on a scheduling-solution feature to solve the backup problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the [SQLite Command Line Shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html):

```
sqlite3 /path/to/live.db '.backup /backup/path.db'
```

This will allow you to backup without causing regular DB operations to fail.  From the documentation:

> The copy operation may be done incrementally, in which case the source
>   database does not need to be locked for the duration of the copy, only
>   for the brief periods of time when it is actually being read from.

Comment: Simple and elegant, and I can even do it from a Windows scheduled task. Thanks!